# Get the AZURE_CREDENTIALS of a Service Principal

Tags: azure, github-actions, credentials

I have already created my service principal.

Using GitHub I need to complete all parameters below. My question is where and how can we find each one?

```
AZURE_CREDENTIALS :
{
  "clientId": "XXX",
  "clientSecret": "XXX",
  "subscriptionId": "XXX",
  "tenantId": "XXX",
  "activeDirectoryEndpointUrl": "XXX",
  "resourceManagerEndpointUrl": "XXX",
  "activeDirectoryGraphResourceId": "XXX",
  "sqlManagementEndpointUrl": "XXX",
  "galleryEndpointUrl": "XXX",
  "managementEndpointUrl": "XXX"
}
```

I've already seen in the documentation that we can generate a JSON file for a new principal service using CLI Azure:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac `
         --name "myApp" --role contributor `
         --scopes /subscriptions/8baa642d-5109-4f1c-b935-401e5b215078/resourceGroups/rg-ai-recommender `
         --sdk-auth
```

But I want to use the existing Service Principal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the command multiple times.

If you run it again, a message will appear stating something like:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name TestPrincipal --role Contributor --sdk-auth
Found an existing application instance of "[existingId]". We will patch it
Creating 'Contributor' role assignment under scope '/subscriptions/[guid]'
  Role assignment already exists.

The output includes credentials that you must protect. Be sure that you do not include these credentials in your code or check the credentials into your source control. For more information, see https://aka.ms/azadsp-cli
'name' property in the output is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use 'appId' instead.
{
  "clientId": "[existingId]",
  "clientSecret": "[aNewSecret]",
  "subscriptionId": "[subscriptionid]",
  // all the other properties
}
```

Of course, this will invalidate the credentials you're using in the other repositories, so you should update those also.

Recovering the secret isn't possible because it's a secret.

This way you can use the same service principal in multiple repositories.

---

Do keep in mind, it might be a more secure strategy to create new service principals for different services/deployments, so you can make the assignments of roles as granular as possible. But that's not what your question is about.

Comment: I think this answer does not address the real question.¿ If I do have my SP password, but not enough privilege to rotate it, how can I get the info needed in that JSON without rotate my credentials?

Comment: If you do have the secret of the service principal, all other values can be retrieved from AAD either manual or via the `az ad sp show --id <id>` command. The key over here is that you do need the `clientSecret`. All of the other stuff can be retrieved via CLI-commands or by checking AAD.

Answer (score 3):

There are three types of service principal:

- Application
- Managed Identity
- Legacy

> You can use the **Enterprise applications** blade in the Azure portal to list and manage the service principals in a tenant. You can see the service principal's permissions, user consented permissions, which users have done that consent, sign in information, and more.

Go to the Azure Portal, open Azure Active Directory and click the [Enterprise Applications](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/AppAppsPreview/menuId/) menu item under Manage.

There, find the registration for the service principal, and find the corresponding information.

To create a new clientSecret for a service principal, find the corresponding registration in [App Registrations](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps) and open up the Certificates & secrets menu under Manage. From there, you can create a new secret. You cannot see values for existing secrets.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, here is where you will get all the info for the json object.

**clientId:** is the applicationId for the Service Principle, if you go to the service principle page in the overview you should see the id.

**clientSecret:** When you create a secret in the Service principle is shows the secret value, it's only shown at create time. Just create a new one if you don't know the secret

**subscriptionId:** if you go to the app where github will be connecting to you should be able to see the subscription ID.

**tenantId:** The Azure active directory app (parent app for the service principles) the tennant Id is shown in the overview

From this page I got all the URLs
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22297

```
"activeDirectoryEndpointUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
"resourceManagerEndpointUrl": "https://management.azure.com/",
"activeDirectoryGraphResourceId": "https://graph.windows.net/",
"sqlManagementEndpointUrl": "https://management.core.windows.net:8443/",
"galleryEndpointUrl": "https://gallery.azure.com/",
"managementEndpointUrl": "https://management.core.windows.net/"
```